# Why can't we use svg or any other image file directly in React?

Tags: reactjs

I was laerning React and wanted to use svg file by using img tag like this `<img src="./images/car.svg"/>` but then I found this statement: `"In order to be able to use SVGs or any other image format in the img <img src={} /> we have to set up a file loader system in whichever module bundler we are using(Webpack, Parcel, etc)"` in here https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/. The question is why can't we use image files directly like this `<img src="./images/car.svg"/>` and we need to use file loader or import files as component?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it like `<img src="images/car.svg"/> //set path properly depend on your tree`. Actually React has no problems with direct image files. You can use svg, png and whatever you need.

Comment: How do you make that work?

Comment: @RamiroPastor, I think you can clarify your question slightly better. I put a path in quotes for `src` param while passing ?absolute? path where my image was located, but without that `./` which you usually use when want to import something. That's it, I hope it can help you somehow